# nVidia Driver keep crashing on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, nvidia-quadro

I have a little problem for about 2-3 weeks now. My nVidia driver crash. The screen comes blank, then one monitor works, the other one no. They flicker, my computer run a lot, like if it was writing on the hard disk. And then, boom! Everything come back and I get this:

[image: nVidia Driver]

I don't know why it does that. I have Windows 8 since the August 16th, but it never did that.

For information, there's my specs:

```
Intel Core2 Duo 3.00Ghz E8400
4GB of DDR2 800Mhz RAM
=> nVidia Quadro 600 PCI-e (with 2 monitors: 1 DP->DVI, 1 DVI->VGA)
Windows 8 Pro with Media Center (genuine, MSDNAA)
```

Comment: Make sure the GPU's fan/heatsink is not packed with dust, or it will overheat and will behave the same way as you described.

Comment: It's a HP dc7900. It has 2 fan in it. And I clean it every months.

Comment: This is an extremely annoying problem that I have yet to track down myself. I experience it most frequently when playing lotro in a window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many applications which worked smooth on Windows7 not working or stopped responding on Win8
Try downloading latest drives form Nvdia site.
And I am not sure about drivers for Windows8 being available.

Comment: It has indeed a new version. I'm downloading it. Oh, it's done (60Mb/s). So now installing, I'll tell you in about 30min if it crash anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Update your driver to the [latest beta](http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro-tesla-win8-win7-winvista-64bit-310.34-beta-driver.html) (fixed). Don't plan on using the stable version for the next few months. Let us know if this fixes anything.

edit--
They [pushed a driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro-tesla-win8-win7-winvista-64bit-307.32-whql-driver.html) on Nov 2nd that you should also try.

Comment: I'm not a beta tester. I had too much problems with beta in the past...

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux Consider Windows 8 a beta :-) . You are running the latest stable version from the error screen-shot you showed us: 306.97.

Comment: That driver isn't for Quadro's, it's for GeForce's and ION's.

Comment: @page4096 this is true...

Comment: @Misha He's not even running the latest stable.

Comment: @Misha I just installed that driver. I think it fixed the problem. But I will see after hours of use...

Comment: @Louis The latest stable of what? My driver or W8?

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux, you were running an older driver, perhaps for the wrong graphics card.

Comment: Hmm, it's the driver Windows Update gave me... That was probably the reason of the bug! But I didn't get the latest from WU, I think nVidia didn't publish it to Microsoft yet.

Answer (score 0):

There has been an ongoing issue with the latestdriver from nvdia and it is constanly conflicting with Microsoft security essentials ,downgrade to older version of n vdia drivers and try opening  internet videos from Google chrome.

Comment: I'm trying to update it to newer version, to see. I hate downgrading! Waste of time!